# How to assign video id to variable and play it in one step?

Tags: javascript, youtube, vuejs2, vue-component

I use [this](https://github.com/anteriovieira/vue-youtube) component

I want to make input field for YouTube video ids and by clicking on a button "play" I want to start video playing. The problem is the next: when I click "play", I see that ID is assigned to `videoId`, but in order to actually start a video playing, I need to click "play" again.

However if `videoId` is hardcoded (`videoId: 'lG0Ys-2d4MA'`), video starts by the 1st click on `play`. Also if input's `v-model="videoId"` (not `providedId`) video is downloading immediately and by clicking on `play` it starts to play, but I do not need auto-downloading once `input` is changed - I want to download video just by clicking on `play`.

Below is the minimal reproducible example

**template**

```
<input type="text" v-model="providedId"/>
<button @click="playVideo">play</button>
<youtube :video-id="videoId" ref="youtube"></youtube>
```

**script**

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
     videoId: '', // <<-- empty srting
     providedId: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    playVideo () {
      this.videoId = this.providedId // <<-- assign video id
      this.player.playVideo()
    },
  },
  computed: {
    player () {
      return this.$refs.youtube.player
    }
  }
}
```

Why video does not start playing after the first click on "play". How to fix it?

Comment: Could you instead of `this.videoId = 'lG0Ys-2d4MA'` try `this.player.loadVideoById('lG0Ys-2d4MA')`? Else I fear its a restriction that videos can only play after an interaction from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

**template**

```
<input type="text"v-model="urlOrId"/>
<button @click="playVideo">play</button>
<youtube :video-id="videoId" :player-vars="playerVars" ref="youtube"></youtube>
```

**script**

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      videoId: '',
      urlOrId: '',
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    player () {
      return this.$refs.youtube.player
    }
  },
  methods: {
    playVideo () {
      // Extract id of the video from URL
      if (this.urlOrId.search('youtube.com') !== -1) {
        this.videoId = this.$youtube.getIdFromUrl(this.urlOrId)
      } else {
        this.videoId = this.urlOrId
      }

      this.player.playVideo()
    }
  }
}
```